# Error Loading Database in Polars/Connectorx

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to load a table from an SQLite database and am getting an error I can't decode. This code works for other tables in this database, so it must be some issue with reading this particular table. Here's my code:

```
conn = "sqlite://database.db"
query = "SELECT * FROM table1"
df = pl.read_database(
                    query, 
                    conn,
                    engine='connectorx'
                )
```

And the traceback is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 df = pl.read_database(
      2                     query, 
      3                     conn,
      4                     engine='connectorx'
      5                 )

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/io/database.py:95, in read_database(query, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol, engine)
     24 """
     25 Read a SQL query into a DataFrame.
     26 
   (...)
     92 
     93 """
     94 if engine == "connectorx":
---> 95     return _read_sql_connectorx(
     96         query,
     97         connection_uri,
     98         partition_on=partition_on,
     99         partition_range=partition_range,
    100         partition_num=partition_num,
    101         protocol=protocol,
    102     )
    103 elif engine == "adbc":
    104     if not isinstance(query, str):

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/io/database.py:224, in _read_sql_connectorx(query, connection_uri, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, protocol)
    219 except ImportError:
    220     raise ImportError(
    221         "connectorx is not installed. Please run `pip install connectorx>=0.3.1`."
    222     ) from None
--> 224 tbl = cx.read_sql(
    225     conn=connection_uri,
    226     query=query,
    227     return_type="arrow2",
    228     partition_on=partition_on,
    229     partition_range=partition_range,
    230     partition_num=partition_num,
    231     protocol=protocol,
    232 )
    234 return from_arrow(tbl)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/connectorx/__init__.py:257, in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
    254 except ModuleNotFoundError:
    255     raise ValueError("You need to install pyarrow first")
--> 257 result = _read_sql(
    258     conn,
    259     "arrow" if return_type in {"arrow", "polars"} else "arrow2",
    260     queries=queries,
    261     protocol=protocol,
    262     partition_query=partition_query,
    263 )
    264 df = reconstruct_arrow(result)
    265 if return_type in {"polars", "polars2"}:

RuntimeError: Conversion error from type Text at index: 0, trailing input
```

This is what the head of the dataframe looks like:

```
    index                       HP_Power    HP_Power_app    HP_PF   HP_L1_Power     HP_L1_Power_app     HP_L1_PF    HP_L2_Power     HP_L2_Power_app     HP_L2_PF    RV_Volts    HP_L1_Voltage   HP_L1_Amps  HP_L2_Amps  RV_Signal
0   2023-01-30 17:21:02+00:00   359545157   509860636   190007960   179712406   253025129   192524  179347720   256835507   190608  3547153805  179156934080    2076666670  2107492180  3084481599
1   2023-01-30 17:21:03+00:00   359547159   509862689   190008935   179713405   253026153   192525  179348723   256836536   190609  3547154472  179157057658    2076674956  2107500508  3084482179
2   2023-01-30 17:21:04+00:00   359549165   509864744   190009912   179714406   253027179   192526  179349728   256837565   190610  3547155162  179157181258    2076683256  2107508837  3084482779
3   2023-01-30 17:21:05+00:00   359551173   509866800   190010888   179715409   253028205   192527  179350733   256838595   190611  3547155890  179157304869    2076691560  2107517168  3084483412
4   2023-01-30 17:21:06+00:00   359553180   509868857   190011864   179716411   253029232   192528  179351738   256839625   190612  3547156762  179157428464    2076699864  210752550
```

Here are my dependancies:

```
pandas==1.5.0
jupyterlab==3.2.9
polars==0.16.13
connectorx==0.3.1
pyarrow==11.0.0
```

Is the issue in how my db table is structured, or can anyone help me understand the traceback?

Comment: You could try `engine="adbc"` to see if the issue is connectorx specific. It may also help to know if other tools can read it, e.g. `pandas.read_sql` or `sqlite3` directly?

Comment: @jqurious Yes, thank you, I should have specified. adbc does work, so it is definitely a connectorx specific issue. Pandas read_sql can read it and I can open it up in DB Browser for SQLite just fine. So it's definitely a connectorx issue. Considering the size of this database, I'm really hoping I can use connectorx for the speed increase.

I have a sneaky suspicion that it's related to the index column being a datetime data type, with the rest being ints.

Comment: Ah okay, so this error is coming directly from connectorx. It looks like it's to do with datetime parsing: https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/406 which links to https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/306

Comment: OK, it does look likely to be that our datetimes aren't perfectly formatted. Thank you @jqurious.